# Why is the Ruelle Transfer Operator a bounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, ergodic-theory

Let $X^+$ be the space of one sided sequences of a finite alphabet. (Analogous to the space of binary sequences, but where we permit $k$ symbols.)

Moreover, define the metric for $x,y\in X^+$ for some $\theta \in (0,1)$ by:

$$ d(x,y) = \theta ^N $$
where $N$ is the largest integer such that $x_i = y_i$ for all $i < N$. Also let $\sigma$ be the left-sided shift map.

In the literature on subshifts of finite types we then commonly encounter the space $F_\theta(X^+) = \Big\{ f : f \text{ is continuous, } var_n f \leq C \theta^n \Big\}$ which denotes the space of $d_\theta$-Lipschitz continuous functions. The norm here is $||f||_\theta = |f|_\infty + |f|_\theta$ where $|f|_\theta = \sup_n \{\frac{var_n f}{\theta^n} \}$ and $ var_n f = \sup \{ |f(x) - f(y)| : x_i = y_i, i < n \}. $

I then wish to show that the operator $L_f:F_\theta(X^+) \to F_\theta(X^+) $ defined by:

$$L_f w(x) = \sum_{y \in \sigma^{-1}(x)} e^{f(y)} w(y)  $$

is a bounded linear operator. Linearity is trivial, and apparently boundedness is too. Unfortunately, I can't seem to see why $L_f$ is bounded. I can't see boundedness because I believe that the sum on the right is infinite and need not converge - though I may be wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I believe the Ruelle transfer operator is the adjoint of the Koopman operator $f\mapsto f\circ T$. If this holds, one can just use the general fact from functional analysis that the adjoint of a bounded linear operator is again bounded.

Comment: @CAPM it seems like you're saying $L_f$ is not even well-defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, $X^+$ has a finite alphabet so the pre-image of any  $x\in X^+$ under the shift map must be a finite set.

You may want to take a look at this [book](http://www.numdam.org/issue/AST_1990__187-188__1_0.pdf) by Parry and Pollicott. Another reference I've been using describes this in some depth is the book *Positive Transfer Operators and Decay of Correlations* by Viviane Baladi.

Comment: Good answer. I eventually realised this myself after I posted the question haha.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that,

$|L_fw(x)|=|\sum_{y \in \sigma^{-1}(x)} e^{f(y)} w(y)|\leqslant \sum_{y \in \sigma^{-1}(x)}| e^{f(y)} w(y)|\leqslant e^{-|f|_\infty}|w|_\infty$.

Dividing in booth sides by $|w|_\infty \neq 0$ and taking the sup for $w\neq 0$ it follows that $L_f$ act as a bounded operator on the space of the continuous functions.

To see that $L_f$ acts as a bounded linear operator on $F_\theta(X^+)$ we just need to show that the Lipschitz constant of $L_fw$ exists. This is also straightforward.

First, each pre image of the set $\sigma^{-1}y$ is the form, $ax=(a, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ where $a\in \{1, \ldots, k\}$.
Secondly, observe that by the Intermediate Value theorem there exists a constant $\gamma$ such that, $|e^{f(x)}-e^{f(y)}|\leqslant \gamma  Lip(f)d_\theta(x,y).$ Therefore,

$$
|L_fw(x)-L_fw(y)|=|\sum_{a\in \{1, \ldots, k\}}w(ax)e^{f(ax)}-\sum_{a\in \{1, \ldots, k\}}w(ay)e^{f(ay)}|
\\
=
\sum_{a\in \{1, \ldots, k\}}
\big[|w(ax)||e^{f(ax)}-e^{f(ay)}|-|e^{f(ay}||w(ax)-w(ay)|\big]
\\
\leqslant
\gamma Lip(f)|w|_\infty \theta d_\theta(x,y)+ e^{|f|_\infty}\theta Lip(w) d_\theta(x,y)
\\
=
\big(\gamma Lip(f)|w|_\infty \theta + e^{|f|_\infty}\theta Lip(w) \big)d_\theta(x,y)
$$
wich implies that $L_fw$ is Lipschitz.